# ECONNREFUSED error during testing with Vitest 0.32.0 + Node JS + Express

Tags: node.js, express, vitest, econnrefused

I'm experiencing a problem while running tests on my Express backend using Axios for making requests and Vitest for test execution. Here are the details:

1. I have my backend running on localhost, port 3000, using Express.
2. I am using Vitest for testing various endpoints that I have implemented.
3. The issue arises when I add more test cases in my test files. Initially, when I run the tests for the first time, everything works fine.
4. However, after adding more tests and saving them, my vitest tests restart (as expected) but throw the following error:

```
Serialized Error: Object {
"address": "::1",
"code": "ECONNREFUSED",
"config": Object {
"adapter": [Array],
"baseURL": "http://localhost:3000/api/users"
...
```

If I restart my Vitest server using my script for Vitest **npm run test**, the first test case works again, but the problem comes up again when I add more tests.

I have checked the Axios configuration, but everything seems to be in order. Additionally, if I make a fetch request to the endpoints from a file separate from my vitest test file customers.test.js, everything works normally.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After analyzing the issue more deeply, I noticed that whenever I added more tests and saved them, my server was also getting restarted. This was happening because I was using **nodemon** to watch for code changes. To fix this and continue using nodemon, you simply need to add the following configuration to your package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myName",
  "type": "module",
  ...
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": ["test/**/*.test.js"]
  }
}
```

In this case, you can replace "test/**/*.test.js" with whatever suits your needs. In my case, my tests are located in the "test/" directory, distributed in subfolders, and all the test files follow the "**name.test.js**" naming structure. There are other ways to add this configuration to nodemon, you can refer to the nodemon documentation at the [nodemon documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#config-files)